# How do I import bookmarks?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

All previous answers appear to be out of date, so, uere goes!
My computer crashed while Tor was open, and it broke.
I have re-installed Tor, searched the wreckage of the broken original but could not find a file which referred to bookmarks.
Can I use my new installation to import the missing bookmarks?
Or, can you tell me where the bookmarks were stored in the original browser¿
                                   Thanking you in advance,  John.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say which operating system, so here is the answer for Linux. Hopefully it will be somewhat similar to what you are using

tor-browser_en-US/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Browser/profile.default/bookmarks.html

You can import it via the bookmarks menu ctrl-shift-o.

Answer (score 0):

did you backup your bookmarks? If yes, here is the step by step guide on how to restore it. Also note that, restoring bookmarks from a backup will overwrite your current set of bookmarks with the ones in the backup file.

1. Click the Library button on your toolbar. (If you don't see it there, click the menu button then click Library.) Click Bookmarks and then click the Show All Bookmarks bar at the bottom.
2. In the Library window, click the Import and Backup button and then select Restore.
3. Select the backup from which you want to restore:

   -The dated entries are automatic backups.

   -(Choose File)… lets you restore from a manual backup.
4. After choosing a backup, your bookmarks from that file will be restored.

   Close the Library window.

However, if you wish to import bookmarks to your newly installed Tor Browser, here are the steps you will need to follow below;

- choose Import Bookmarks from HTML….
- Within the Import Bookmarks File window that opens, navigate to the bookmarks HTML file you are importing and select the file.
- Click the Open button. The Import Bookmarks File window will close.
- Close the Library window.

The bookmarks in the selected HTML file will be added to your Tor bookmarks within the Bookmarks Menu directory.

You may need to backup your bookmarks after importing. so here are the steps If you wish to Backup

-Choose Backup

-A new windows opens and you have to choose the location to save the file. The file has a .json extension.